# Calculate median using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do I calculate the median for a range of more than 30 values using VBA? The `WorkSheetFormula` method can handle only 30 values. My function at the moment looks like this;

```
Function medval(Longitudes As Range)
'I want the median for values in the range (here 'Longitudes') B2:B100)
End Function
```

Comment: `The WorkSheetFormula method can handle only 30 values` - it can take up to 30 _separate_ ranges/values as parameters, but `WorksheetFunction.Median(Longitudes)` still works, no matter how many cell in `Longitudes` range

Comment: Thanks @simoco . I've been complicating a lot of simple things today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can average/find median of as many contiguous data values as you want:

`=MEDIAN(A1:A65500)` will work

but you cannot exceed 30 individual references in Excel 2003 (in 2007 you can have 255 references).

i.e.

`=MEDIAN(A1,A2,A3,...A31)`  will not work.

A range of values will work as long as they are contiguous

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been complicating simple things today